# Not able to run flutter pedometer plugin on android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, pedometer

## Background

I am new to flutter and need to implement a step counter.
I found the pedometer plugin for flutter, but can not get the example code to run.
I am using visual studio code and android studio. I get the following error.

## Error

```
E/flutter (11300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(1, StepDetection not available, StepDetection is not available on this device)

I/flutter (11300): ERROR: StepCount not available
```

I have added the following line to my androidmanifest as instructed by the documentation:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION/>
```

Any ideas why this does not work?
Is it not possible to test pedometer apps on an android emulator? I have tested on pixel 2 and pixel 3.

I have an Iphone and i am working on a Windows computer, so i can not test it on a physical device.

Comment: I just got an android phone and the code now works. Seems as though the pedometer plugin does not work on emulator.

Comment: Pedometer 3.0.0
It works on my Samsung Galaxy S7,
but it does not work on my Samsung A02s and on my iOS Simulator